# laravel 4.2 session causing issue in internet explorer 11

Tags: session, laravel-4, internet-explorer-11

I am facing some strange issue in IE 11. However its working in FF and chrome well.

Let me try to explain in deep.

I have URL like this

```
https://www.printhubpro.co.uk/ryman
```

And rout for this URL is,

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'DesignerController@getClient');
```

And in controller function

```
public static function getClient($slug)
{
    // Check if the client exists
    $client = User::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    if (! $client) {
        return View::make('error.404');
    }

    Session::put('client', $client->toArray());
    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Which sets the session and redirects user to main site.

Now i have designer here, which uses fabricJs,

```
https://www.printhubpro.co.uk/designer/new/2002
```

Now on this designer, If i press `Order this template` it shows login popup.
And just register.

Its working in FF and chrome but not in IE 11. I checked and seems like session not working proper after login. It removes all sessions.

Here is Ajax login route,

```
Route::post('ajax/login', 'AjaxController@postLogin');
```

And controller function

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    // Validate input
    $validator = Validator::make($input, array(
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ));

    // Validation failed
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $messages = $validator->messages();

        return array('error' => $messages->first());
    }


        $credentials = array(
            'username' => $input['username'],
            'password' => $input['password'],
            'store_id' => Session::get('client.id')
        );
    // Get their credentials

    // Failed to auth
    if (! Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return array('error' => Lang::get('messages.login.fail'));
    }

    // Store their canvas
    if (isset($input['canvas'])) {
        Session::put('canvas.flash', $input['canvas']);
    }

    // If they're a client set the client
    if (Auth::user()->role == Config::get('constants.roles.client')) {
        Session::put('client', Auth::user()->toArray());
    }

    // Successfully logged in
    return 1;
}
```

And after login i am redirecting to main site again. But issue is after login there is no session so when redirecting i am getting error because of no session.